# How to remove URL in the tags WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to remove the URL from the tag name. Please let me know. how to achieve this.
Screenshot Link - https://i.ibb.co/grSPH7t/Screenshot-1.png

Thanks

Comment: The solution is already on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/182527/remove-url-from-tag

Answer (score 0):

Try By Code :

```
<?php
$postalltags = get_the_tags();
if ($postalltags) {
  foreach($postalltags as $singletag) {
    echo $singletag->name . ' '; 
  }
}
?>
```